# How to use sliders to change how region varies with varying parameters (sympy)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, sympy

I have a problem using sympy.

I have to plot regions that satisfies few inequalities.

There are 3 parameters u, c, and q, which are all between (0,1), and I want to see how the region changes as one parameter varies.

In the code below, I fixed one parameter 'q', to see which parameters 'u' and 'c' satisfy the inequalities.

Currently, I have to manually change the fixed value q to a different float to see how region changes.

Is there any way I can use sliders to see how the region changes continuously?

Thank you.

I'm new to python and plotting.

It doesn't have to be Sympy, matplotlib, or plotly as long as my needs are satisfied.

Here is the code I wrote below

```
import sympy
from sympy import And, symbols, plot_implicit

u, c = symbols('u c')
q = 0.5


m2 = 2 * sympy.sqrt(c*q*u)
k2 = (m2 - 2 * c) / m2
a2 = (m2 * (m2 - 2 * c)) / (2 * c * q)
b2 = (m2 ** 2 - c * ( 1 + q ) * m2) / (2 * c * q)
            

t3 = u - c + 1
k3 = (q * t3 - sympy.sqrt(c * q * t3 + 1 - c))/(q * t3 + 1 - c)
a3 = (2 * c * k3 ) / (q * (1 - k3)**2)
b3 = (u - c - ((c * (k3 **2)) / (q * ((1 - k3)**2)))) / ( 1- k3)
d3 = (- 1 + ((1 - k3) / c) - ((1 - k3)*(u - c - (u - c - ((c * (k3 **2)) / (q * ((1 - k3)**2)))))) / c ) * (1 - k3)
m3 = (2 * c * d3) / ((1 - k3)**2)



p1 = plot_implicit(And( 2 * (1 - u) < 1, u > (c + 4 + sympy.sqrt(c**2 + 8*c)) / 8 , u >= (4*q + c + sympy.sqrt(c**2 + 8 * q * c)) / (8 * q)), x_var = (u, 0, 1), y_var = (c, 0, 1), line_color = 'red', show=False)
p2 = plot_implicit(And( b2 + m2 <=1 , a2 > 0, u>c ), x_var = (u,0,1), y_var = (c, 0, 1), line_color = 'green', show=False)
p3 = plot_implicit(And(u>c, k3>0, d3>0, b3>a3, b3+m3 <=1, k3+d3 < 1) , x_var = (u, 0, 1), y_var = (c, 0, 1), show = False)

p1.append(p2[0])
p1.append(p3[0])

p1.show()
```

Any references or skeleton code will help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use the following libraries:

- [SymPy Plot Backend](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for data generation. This package is capable of creating interactive plots with sliders. However, this functionality is not yet implemented for `plot_implicit`. Nonetheless, I'll use it to create the numerical data to be plotted.
- Matplotlib, in particular I'm going to follow the [slider demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html).

Note that you are plotting boolean expressions (created with sympy's `And`). Consequently, the `ImplicitSeries` used to generate the numerical data will use an adaptive algorithm, which is slow! So, whenever you'll move the slider you will have to wait a few seconds for the update to be rendered on the screen.

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
from spb.series import ImplicitSeries
from spb.backends.matplotlib import _matplotlib_list
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

u, c, q = symbols('u c q')
init_q = 0.5

m2 = 2 * sqrt(c*q*u)
k2 = (m2 - 2 * c) / m2
a2 = (m2 * (m2 - 2 * c)) / (2 * c * q)
b2 = (m2 ** 2 - c * ( 1 + q ) * m2) / (2 * c * q)
t3 = u - c + 1
k3 = (q * t3 - sqrt(c * q * t3 + 1 - c))/(q * t3 + 1 - c)
a3 = (2 * c * k3 ) / (q * (1 - k3)**2)
b3 = (u - c - ((c * (k3 **2)) / (q * ((1 - k3)**2)))) / ( 1- k3)
d3 = (- 1 + ((1 - k3) / c) - ((1 - k3)*(u - c - (u - c - ((c * (k3 **2)) / (q * ((1 - k3)**2)))))) / c ) * (1 - k3)
m3 = (2 * c * d3) / ((1 - k3)**2)

i1 = And( 2 * (1 - u) < 1, u > (c + 4 + sqrt(c**2 + 8*c)) / 8 , u >= (4*q + c + sqrt(c**2 + 8 * q * c)) / (8 * q))
i2 = And( b2 + m2 <=1 , a2 > 0, u>c )
i3 = And(u>c, k3>0, d3>0, b3>a3, b3+m3 <=1, k3+d3 < 1)


def compute_inequality(i, val):
    # generate numerical data for matplotlib fill method
    i = i.subs(q, val)
    s = ImplicitSeries(i, (u, 0, 1), (c, 0, 1))
    return _matplotlib_list(s.get_data()[0])

# create the figure and initialize the regions
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
region1, = ax.fill(*compute_inequality(i1, init_q))
region2, = ax.fill(*compute_inequality(i2, init_q))
region3, = ax.fill(*compute_inequality(i3, init_q))

# adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# Make a horizontal slider to control the frequency.
ax_q = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
q_slider = Slider(
    ax=ax_q,
    label='q',
    valmin=0,
    valmax=5,
    valinit=init_q,
)

# The function to be called anytime a slider's value changes
def update(val):
    region1.set_xy(np.c_[compute_inequality(i1, val)])
    region2.set_xy(np.c_[compute_inequality(i2, val)])
    region3.set_xy(np.c_[compute_inequality(i3, val)])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# register the update function with each slider
q_slider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. However, when I ran it in my VS code, the slider comes out but it doesn't move. The slider and the graph are as if they are a single image as a whole. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try a web search to enable interactive matplotlib plots with VS code. I've tried that example in Jupyter Notebook and it worked by running `%matplotlib widget` at the beginning of the notebook.